# two fields record congruence in Agda

Tags: agda, category-theory, theorem-proving

I'd like to write the Limit in Sets Category using `Agda`. Assuming local smallness, a functor is a pair of a map on Set OC and I, like this.

```
 sobj :  OC →  Set  c₂
 smap : { i j :  OC  }  → (f : I ) →  sobj i → sobj j
```

A cone for the functor is a record with two fields. Using the record, commutativity of the cone and the properties of the Limit
are easily shown, except the uniqueness. The uniqueness of the Limit is turned out that a congruence of the records with two fields.

In the following agda code, I'd like to prove snat-cong lemma.

```
open import Level
module S where

open import Relation.Binary.Core
open import Function
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

record snat   { c₂ }  { I OC :  Set  c₂ } ( sobj :  OC →  Set  c₂ )
     ( smap : { i j :  OC  }  → (f : I ) →  sobj i → sobj j ) : Set  c₂ where
   field
       snmap : ( i : OC ) → sobj i
       sncommute : ( i j : OC ) → ( f :  I ) →  smap f ( snmap i )  ≡ snmap j
   smap0 :  { i j :  OC  }  → (f : I ) →  sobj i → sobj j
   smap0 {i} {j} f x =  smap f x

open snat

snat-cong :  { c : Level }  { I OC :  Set  c }  { SObj :  OC →  Set  c  } { SMap : { i j :  OC  }  → (f : I )→  SObj i → SObj j }
         ( s t :  snat SObj SMap   )
     → ( ( λ i  → snmap s i )  ≡  ( λ i →  snmap t i ) )
     → ( ( λ i j f →  smap0 s f ( snmap s i )  ≡ snmap s j   ) ≡ (  ( λ  i j f → smap0 t f ( snmap t i )  ≡ snmap t j ) ) )
     → s ≡ t
snat-cong s t refl refl = {!!}
```

This is quite simlar to the answer of 
[Equality on dependent record types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488098/equality-on-dependent-record-types) .

So it should work something like

```
snat-cong s t refl refl = refl
```

but it gives an error like this.

```
.sncommute i j f != sncommute t i j f of type
.SMap f (snmap t i) ≡ snmap t j
```

Is there any help?

Comment: I'm not sure what your third argument to `snat-cong` is supposed to mean, can you elaborate on that? Do you mean `(∀ i j f → (smap0 s f (snmap s i) ≡ snmap s j) ≡ (smap0 t f (snmap t i) ≡ snmap t j))`?

Comment: It is the same using functional extensionality,   {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} {f g : (x : A) → B x} → (∀ x → f x ≡ g x) → f ≡ g → ( λ x → f x ≡ λ x → g x )

Answer (score 1):

In `snat-cong` none of the arguments are saying assuming anything about `sncommute s` being equal to `sncommute t`. Instead what you are saying is that the *type* of `sncommute s` is equal to the type of `sncommute t`, but that already follows from the first equality.

The easiest way to state equality of the `sncommute`s itself is with heterogeneous equality. So snat-cong could look something like this:

```
open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality using (_≅_;refl)

snat-cong : {c : Level}
            {I OC : Set c}
            {sobj : OC → Set c}
            {smap : {i j : OC}  → (f : I) → sobj i → sobj j}
          → (s t : snat sobj smap)
          → (snmap-≡ : snmap s ≡ snmap t)
          → (sncommute-≅ : sncommute s ≅ sncommute t)
          → s ≡ t
snat-cong _ _ refl refl = refl
```

If you want to be more explicit, or want to work with `--without-K`, then you could use a dependent equality type for `sncommute-≅`:

```
snat-cong' : {c : Level}
             {I OC : Set c}
             {sobj : OC → Set c}
             {smap : {i j : OC}  → (f : I) → sobj i → sobj j}
             (s t : snat sobj smap)
           → (snmap-≡ : snmap s ≡ snmap t)
           → (sncommute-≡ : subst (\snmap → ∀ i j f → smap f (snmap i) ≡ snmap j) snmap-≡ (sncommute s) ≡ sncommute t)
           → s ≡ t
snat-cong' _ _ refl refl = refl
```

Comment: Ah, that make sense. Thanks.

Comment: I've finished my proof as http://www.cr.ie.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/hg/Members/kono/Proof/category/file/07c84c8d9e4f/SetsCompleteness.agda